# Reasons for UK visitors refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

My visa was refused because I stated I am a student but the information provided does not demonstrate I am a student or currently enrolled in an academic institution. And it is also unclear in the information provided how I am financially supported to meet the cost of living in my country.

I want to know what the refusal means and my next step I can take in applying for my visitors visa.

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. As is written the question is unclear. Please add an actual question. Do you want to know what the refusal means? Or what next steps you can take? Please also post a copy of your refusal letter (After blanking personal details). You can also search for refusal questions as there is high chance someone has already asked (and got an answer to) the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: @lkponmwosa What evidence did you provide to prove your education status? What income did you state you live off and what evidence did you provide to prove it? Did you follow the documentation guidance in https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk?

Comment: I didn't provide any educational evidence. I didn't state any income I live on. But my aunt had been helping me because am a student am not working so I used her bank details.

Comment: Yes please. I want to know what the refusal means and my next step I can take in applying for my visitors visa.

Comment: It means what it says: they need evidence of your being a student and your financial situation. This might help: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @lkponmwosa Read the answer to the duplicate question and the UK guidance on supporting evidence. **Don’t** reapply until you understand what documentation UKVI look for *and* you can provide it. Otherwise you’ll just be wasting your money because you’ll get another refusal.