# Evidence of Bank statement

Tags: uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

My aunt opened a bank account on my name in England since May 2019 with 3500 pounds. Can I use it as my bank statement?

Comment: @lkponmwosa Idemudia If the account is in your name there is no reason why you can’t use it AFAIK. You would also need to provide evidence of the source of the £3,500, for example a bank statement from May 2019 showing the transfer of the funds to your account, and *why* the money was given. You might also have to explain why someone who isn’t a UK resident has a UK bank account

Comment: Is this question related to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162195/reasons-for-uk-visitors-refusal?

Comment: We assume you are applying for a UK visa. What kind of visa are you applying for? Please edit those details into the question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the bank account is solely in your name, and you can withdraw money from it whenever you want, then you can use it as evidence that you own that much money.

UK immigration require you to provide details of your **entire financial situation**, including day to day transactions. If you have not been using this account for your normal banking, and especially if there have been few transactions since May 2019, then you will need to provide additional evidence of what your day-to-day finances are like. A single bank account with little activity will not satisfy this requirement.

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) will give you much more information about what you need to provide by way of financial information.

Comment: I have not been using the account for daily transaction, I haven't withdraw money from the account. I have only the bank statement every other documents is with my aunt

Comment: Then the account will only be useful in saying "I have 3500 pounds available to me." You also need to provide details of your day to day finances. But also why does your aunt have the documents? Do you own the account? Is anyone apart from you able to withdraw from he account?

Comment: But won't the embassy think that's a reason not to return back to my country???

Comment: @IkponmwosaIdemudia Please edit the question to include what kind of visa you are applying for, and confirming that you are applying for a UK visa.

Comment: @Ikponmwosa Idemudia You don’t say where you will be applying from, why your aunt opened a bank account in England in your name in 2019, or how you have access to the money from outside the UK. However the financial circumstances you are describing do not appear ‘normal’ for a visitor visa application. As it stands, money in an account in the UK is **not** a credible tie to your home country, and it’s doubtful proof of funds unless you can show the source of the money and that you have access to it. Most UK high street banks normally only open an account for UK residents

Comment: @Traveller I doubt source of funds will be a problem if it's been in the account for nearly two years. The other stuff will be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I want to use the bank statement to apply for a visitors visa

Comment: @lkponmwosa Idemudia What is the date of the bank statement? Ideally it should be dated within a month of the visa application date; older than that would mean it’s less likely to be deemed acceptable and that would become increasingly likely the older the statement is.